# Matching and capturing multiple names in a string

Tags: regex

I have a sentence that might look like this:

> Name1, Name2, Name4, Name5 have liked your image

or like this

> Name1, Name2, Name4 and Name5 have liked your image

I need a regular experssion to match all names. I've managed to grab all first four names in both cases with one expression, but somehow I'm failing to get `Name5` from these and I can't figure out why.

This is my regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+(?=,| and)
```

---

**Demo:** http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3U4  (click `preg_match_all`)
**Demo2**: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3U5  (is the version that works, please confirm)

---

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture all names this way regarding on your example

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+(?=,| and| have)
```

Detail: `.` does not need to be escaped when into brackets

Answer (score 0):

Your regex requires one of the strings `","` or`" and"` to follow the match (that's what the [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=,| and)` is there for). Neither of them does so for `Name5`.

Comment: How do I use positive lookbehind correctly in this situation? I tried using: `(?<=, |and )` here, but it's pretty much obvious that it wont work. I want to allow having a _comma + space_ or _and + space_ before the match, but not include it. This?: `(?<=, |and |^)[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+`